# Allow external user to start/stop Google Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I have a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance in which I created a new user (through `adduser`) to allow a developer work in the instance. Now he has SSH access and can login in the instance but I want him to be able to start/stop the instance so it doesn't run when he's not working on it to prevent charging when it's idle. Ideally, he can install `gcloud` and just run the `gcloud compute instances start/stop` command but no other commands

I looked at the IAM roles and there doesn't appear to be a Compute Instance User role. Is it possible to grant external users this ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as they have a Google Account of any sort. [Here's how to do it](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access); indeed, it looks like you'll want to [create a custom IAM role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) and give them [`instances.reset`, `instances.start`, and `instances.stop`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam-permissions#instances_collection) on the instance(s) in question.

[Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/identity/) might be the right tool to use to grant them access if they're not in your company; more info [here](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7389973).

By the way, `adduser` is not the right way to go about allowing an extra user to access an instance; [OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#external_user) is the right tool for the job. (There's also another, now-deprecated, method: [adding their SSH key to the instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only addition I had to make was also to add the `compute.instances.get` permission, because without it it wasn't possible to start/stop the instance. Now the only problem is that the user can start/stop any instance under the same project, not just a specific one.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to get this working so that the user can only stop, start specific instances?